# XML Error when I try to do simplexml_load_file

Tags: php, arrays, xml, simplexml

I am trying to turn a XML data from another website into arrays in my program. This is what I have written so far:

```
<?php
$rss = 'http://headlines.yahoo.co.jp/rss/asahik-dom.xml';
$xml = simplexml_load_file($rss);
var_dump($xml);
?>
```

However, when I try to load the php page, it comes up with this error:

> Warning: simplexml_load_file(http://headlines.yahoo.co.jp/rss/asahik-dom.xml) [function.simplexml-load-file]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! in /home/www2/it32.lady2.itall.co.jp/www/yxml.php on line 11
>
> Warning: simplexml_load_file() [function.simplexml-load-file]: I/O warning : failed to load external entity "http://headlines.yahoo.co.jp/rss/asahik-dom.xml" in /home/www2/it32.lady2.itall.co.jp/www/yxml.php on line 11
>       bool(false)
>
> FYI the $xml = simplexml_load_file($rss); is line 11.

Which part of my code has gone wrong?
Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Please try `file_get_contents()` to load file and then use `SimpleXMLElement` to parse it.

Try

```
$rss = file_get_contents('http://headlines.yahoo.co.jp/rss/asahik-dom.xml');
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($rss);
print_r($xml);
```

**NOTE** `allow_url_fopen` must be enabled in `php.ini`

Comment: This is what comes up: `Warning: file_get_contents(http://headlines.yahoo.co.jp/rss/asahik-dom.xml) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! in /home/www2/it32.lady2.itall.co.jp/www/yxml.php on line 10

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'String could not be parsed as XML' in /home/www2/it32.lady2.itall.co.jp/www/yxml.php:11 Stack trace: #0 /home/www2/it32.lady2.itall.co.jp/www/yxml.php(11): SimpleXMLElement->__construct('') #1 {main} thrown in /home/www2/it32.lady2.itall.co.jp/www/yxml.php on line 11`

Comment: @MasayukiTonoki it seems like `allow_url_fopen` is not enabled in your `php.ini`.